# Encoding/decoding CGFloat on 32- vs 64-bit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, types, 32bit-64bit

I'm converting an app to work in 64-bit. The Apple docs state that the `CGFloat` type is a `float` on 32-bit and a `double` on 64-bit.

If that is so, how do you handle encoding/decoding of the value? For instance, if creating an `NSNumber` from a `CGFloat`, should I use the `-numberWithFloat:` or `-numberWithDouble:` method of NSNumber? The same question applies to the `NSCoder` and `NSKeyedArchiver` methods `-encodeFloat:forKey:` and `-encodeDouble:forKey:`.

Do I have to write a conditional macro so that `-numberWithFloat:` is called on 32-bit and `-numberWithDouble:` on 64-bit?

What happens if a user running the 64-bit version of the app saves a file where these values are encoded as doubles and the file is opened/unarchived on a 32-bit system?

All the methods in my app that use `CGFloats` are unlikely to ever need the precision level of a `double`, so should I even be worrying about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What happens if a user running the 64-bit version of the app saves a file where these values are encoded as doubles and the file is opened/unarchived on a 32-bit system?

Nothing special. The file contains a `double`, and presumably you're sending `decodeDouble:forKey:` to retrieve the value, so you'll get a `double`. You can then cast it to `CGFloat`—which will lose precision if you're on a 32-bit machine, but you have to do that cast sooner or later. (Even if you hold onto the `double`, you'll still have to cast to `CGFloat` when you pass the value to Quartz/AppKit/UIKit.)

Consider the alternative: You store `float`s in the file on a 64-bit machine, and then load the file back in on the same machine. You and Quartz can handle the full precision of the 64-bit `double` type, but you don't have it, because you threw it away when you wrote out the file. If the value changed at all in the cast, that change is now permanent.

So my recommendation is to always use the `double` type with NSKeyedArchiver, unless you know that you are *never* going to use anything but `float` (i.e., the target API only uses `float`, never `double`). This isn't true of Quartz, so for `CGFloat`, use `double`.